# How to customize "Download CSV" functionality in HighCharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, export-to-csv

by default when we use "Download CSV" button to download report, we just get the same common data which were used while creating chart. But if I want to download more data along with those then how to achieve that?

Comment: By default, all points are exported: http://jsfiddle.net/ohzwbr5a/, however when you use Highstock then situation is different.

Comment: yeah, but if I want to download more custom data which are not showing in chart but it will be shown only in csv file, then how would I do that? I am using mysql to fetch data from db.

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net? It will allow us your chart configuration, data etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve the same by adding the new item to the menu like this:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Download custom CSV',
    onclick: function () {
       /* Add your custom logic to download CSV file with desired data*/
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I have already achieved what I want. I use the same way, you show here. Thanks once again.